# Guitar Pro 7 - converting Midi to Ukulele

Tags: midi, ukulele

I am trying to convert a midi to a ukulele GCEA.
But as you can see from the screnshot below it's giving me some notes that do not have such notes.
There are not so many frets....

Can anybody please help convert it the right way?
I searched on youtube too, but also there nothing helped.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: you have to transpose the midi melody 2 octaves up with guitar pro, then the tab notation may be playable.

Comment: can you please explain how to do that? I am really new to this soft. I am thinking to buy it, but I am on trial mode now. I am trying to lear. If you prefer not to explain, maybe you can suggest some tutorial that explains how to transpose it?

Comment: have you googled *transposing tab on guitar pro*? there are tutorials and online apps. you can also add to each fret nr. the same amount of frets, maybe 24 (or in another key another  amount like + 18 , this should work too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to transpose the midi melody 2 octaves up with guitar pro, then the tab notation may be playable

> Transposing to Ukulele
> A big advantage of Guitar Pro is the amount of tabs for it that can be found on the web. Ultimate Guitar is a great source (you even find my pre Uke Hunt guitar tabs on there).

It’s easy to transfer tabs from guitar (or bass or whatever) to ukulele. You just copy it from the original tab and paste it into a ukulele tab.

The big problem you’ll come across is that most guitar parts will have notes that are too low to played on the ukulele. These are just turned into rests by Guitar Pro. You need to transpose the tab up into the ukulele’s range.

You can transpose any piece of tab by selecting the part you want to transpose then going to Tools > Transpose. That brings up a box with a few options. Choose how many semitones up you want to transpose it (one semitone = one fret) then OK it. You can also transpose the whole track (by selecting “All bars”) or all the instruments in the tab (“All tracks”).

There are a couple of ways you can approach transposing to ukulele. If you don’t care about what key it is in, find the lowest note in the tab and work out how much you have to transpose it upwards until it reaches the C of a ukulele (or whatever the lowest note you’ve got in the tuning you’re using).

If you want to keep it in the same key you need to transpose the track up by an octave (+12). It’s possible you’ll still have notes that are too low. In that case, transpose up another octave.

[transposing on  guitar pro for ukulele](http://ukulelehunt.com/2016/03/30/making-ukulele-tabs-with-guitar-pro/)